# Which nosql db fits?

Tags: node.js, nosql, scaling, riak

I am looking to build a type of social network. Now this isn't going to be Facebook scale but I feel like it could have a large following. I want to build the system with scalability in mind. It also needs to be able to handle a lot of data and relationships. I was hoping someone could give me some direction of what db to use. I have read a lot of articles but they are usually at least a year old and the databases are changing fast so I don't know whether the things people are saying still hold true. I really like the riak database because it is really easy to scale and I like the fact that all of the nodes can read and write. One of my concerns is the relationships the data is going to have. However, I believe that links in riak will solve this problem. But in using links will that decrease the performance. I am just hoping someone could give me some direction with experience and the way the databases are currently.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reviews on that topic: [by thoughtworks](http://www.thoughtworks.com/articles/nosql-comparison) (and some in Fowler's book), and some in [Cassandra vs MongoDB vs CouchDB vs Redis vs Riak vs HBase vs Membase vs Neo4j comparison](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis). According to them you'd need either "Graph database" or "Distributed Peer Store" (Riak is listed here), or, which would be better - some combination of them. If performance is your main concern, I'd also suggest to start modeling of highly loaded scenarios and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am most definitely going to run some high load tests. I just want to narrow down my choices before going down that path. Like to get it down to 2 or 3. Yeah riak is really interesting to me. Do u have any input on how efficient relationships are.

Comment: @ngreenwood6 just before we go into a discussion - could you outline an expected data model in your question? That would a little bit specify and narrow "a lot of data and relationships" question to more concrete one.

Answer (score 1):

This question's probably open to too much debate. But all the same; it sounds like you should stay away from simple key-value like say, redis, and towards something that's more of an object store for the rich, even relational, metadata you have; like MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have read that mongodb is kinda difficult to scale and on top of that it doesn't handle a lot of data very well. One other thing to note of is relationships. I know u could keep the relationships in mongodb in a single object (probably by ids) but they have a limited amount of space (16mb now if I remember correctly) so at some point that may be a problem.

Comment: I don't have a source, but I remember our ops dept. saying mongo could only hold about 1 million records or something like that. I hope I don't start a flame war. Mongo can do relations pretty well, but you do have to maintain integrity yourself. Redis is too simple for what you need (key/value store). I would go with either mysql, or mongodb. Not sure about couchdb.